# Multiple data validations in google sheets problem

Tags: google-sheets, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown menu in A1 but I want it to reject input if B1 says "Closed". It won't let me keep the dropdown box as soon as I create the data validation for rejecting input. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to add 2 different data validation criteria in the selected range.

One workaround that you could do is to use data validation to have a drop-down menu and create an [onEdit()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) function in Apps Script that will reject the inputs.

**Sample Code:**

```
function onEdit(e){

  var cell = e.range;
  var col = e.range.getColumn();
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  //Check if current edited cell is in column 1 and if the cell besides the current cell is Closed
  if(col == 1 && cell.offset(0,1).getValue() == "Closed"){

    //Display warning message
    ui.alert(
      'Warning',
      'You cannot modify cells that are closed, returning the original value of the cell',
      ui.ButtonSet.OK
    )
    //return cell to its original value
    cell.setValue(e.oldValue);
  }
}
```

**What it does?**

1. Check if the modified cell is in column 1 and verify if the adjacent cell on its right has the value "Closed"
2. If true, display a warning message and return the cell to its original value

**Output:**

[image]

I used [Range.offset(rowOffset, columnOffset)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range?hl=en#offsetrowoffset,-columnoffset) to get the value of the cell on the right side of the current cell by using +1 as column offset.

---

**Additional Reference:**

[Container-bound Scripts](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound?hl=en)

[Google Sheets events](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events?hl=en#google_sheets_events)