# security to lock entire ROW using other cell value

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

***I want to lock the row on the basis of input in other cell***

For example, I have 4 Column ( Name, Contact Number, Product and Status) Now I want to auto lock the all 3 rows on the basis of Input in Status column (I am using Dropdown list in Status column) i.e. As soon I select (Closed and DROP) value from the List of Status Dropdown column all the row from (A1 to H1) get blocked.

---

**Currently, I am Using JavaScript whose author is RON M**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/65709032/20113620

It is working fine, I am able to lock the Column C which is Dropdown List if **input value in Column D is Closed**

But I want to apply this in all Selected Row i.e (A1 to C1)

---

I am attaching Google sheet of my working for better understating
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Tqjd2QFJRSEIA_B6z5aCFXhA0_Ia4vxmETRsMbJd4SE/edit?usp=sharing

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to [so]. The code is uncomplete. Once said that, please show what you tried / make a the question more specific that just providing a requirement and add a brief description of your search efforts to find helpful posts from this site.

Comment: By the way the code in the question apparently doesn't match the description as it check the status in column B rather than in column H.

Comment: Let me explain in details

Comment: Let me explain in details, I have Four Column in google sheet, A,B,C,D( Name, Contact, Product, Status ) Now I want to block the A to C Rows on the basis of any value select in "Status" Cell that is Cell D. I am able to lock only C Row through script given above. I want to lock row A,B,C   I am attaching a sheet link for more reference..   https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Tqjd2QFJRSEIA_B6z5aCFXhA0_Ia4vxmETRsMbJd4SE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Code Source -  https://stackoverflow.com/a/65709032/20113620

Comment: Just to be clear you are not really locking anything and in fact if you change things fast enough the on edit probably wont be able to keep up and things that you think should have been locked can get changed.  For example if you paste multiple changes at the same time the onEdit will not be able to keep up.  I am not saying this to be critical of your code, but you said you are an accountant and so I'm sure the accountants I know might consider this an unacceptable weakness.

Comment: Dear Cooper thank you for your reply.  please suggest any solution for the same. paste function is not working in selected cell and I need a report through this so I will manage the data and input in the prescribed manner so the I can the true result for the same

Comment: It looks like you copied this from somewhere else. If you're using someone else's work without giving them credit, that constitutes plagiarism, which is not welcome on Stack Exchange. To fix it, you can [edit], include a [link](/editing-help#links) to the source, mention the author's name, and [quote](/editing-help#simple-blockquotes) the copied content. For more details, see [referencing help](/help/referencing) and [this FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160077/343832).

Comment: Dear TheMaster I have changed as you suggested for the same, Please have a look. your help is highly helpful to me

Answer (score 0):

You only need to update the condition of the `if` statement to check A,B and C columns, in this case 1,2,3.

```js
function onEdit(e){

  var cell = e.range;
  var col = e.range.getColumn();
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  //Check if current edited cell is in column 3 and if the cell besides the 5 cell is Closed
  if(col == "1" || col == "2" || col == "3" && cell.offset(0,1).getValue() == "Closed"){

    //Display warning message
    ui.alert(
      'Warning',
      'You cannot modify cells that are closed, returning the original value of the cell',
      ui.ButtonSet.OK
    )
    //return cell to its original value
    cell.setValue(e.oldValue);
  }
}
```

##### Documentation:

- [If statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else)
- [Logical OR (||) Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR)

---

#### Update

```
function onEdit(e){

  var cell = e.range;
  var col = e.range.getColumn();
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var sS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  
  sS.getRange(10,10).setValue(e.range.getColumn())
  if(sS.getRange(row,3).getValue()==="Closed" || col !== "3"){
    ui.alert(
      'Warning',
      'You cannot modify cells that are closed, returning the original value of the cell',
      ui.ButtonSet.OK
    )
    cell.setValue(e.oldValue);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Emel for your reply. After Implement this Script I am Facing Two Problems.           1st is, I am not able to input new value in cell between A to C even there is not value in Cell D, It is showing cannot modify cells. I want if I input DROP value from the Cell of D Then I can change the value in A to C otherwise not.                                                          
2nd is if I am Changing value in cell D then all other cell is blocked but I am able to change value in Cell C that is dropdown list

Comment: This is happening due the use of `offset` in the range, you need to get the row also and use [`getRange`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column) in order to capture the correct cell.

Comment: thank you so much Emel, Please help me our through write the script here only

Comment: Can you provide a sanitized copy of the sheet? The one posted in the question is inaccessible

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Tqjd2QFJRSEIA_B6z5aCFXhA0_Ia4vxmETRsMbJd4SE/edit?usp=sharing please try this one... I want that if I entered any value "It cloud be closed, Followup, Lost"  in 4 column then only  A,B,C "Three  Row "get closed means no one will able to change the cell, but in column 4 will able to change the status from followup to Closed or Lost